# order of operations for ambiguous vertical division

Tags: arithmetic, divisibility

consider the following two problems from Princeton's Quant GRE prep
[problem 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjDs7.png)
[problem 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbSLY.png)

Why am i meant to assume that a/b/c should be read as a/(b/c)? I would assume it should be read as a ÷ b ÷ c, and therefore (a  ÷ b)  ÷ c, considering that the same operations are performed left to right.

Furthermore my answer to question 1 was identical to the question. Could this be a problem with the way my browser displays the questions?

Is Princeton correct in asserting that a/b/c should be assumed to state a/(b/c)?

Sorry about such a pedestrian question, I've been having trouble finding someone to answer it and my exam is tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The division is in fact not ambiguous in those questions if you look very closely at the sizes of the vinculums( the line between numerator and denominator) it can be seen that one is larger than the other, granted it could stand to be much clearer ( i had to zoom in on paint for the second one ).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that, in the first question, the $+$ signs indicate that they are of the form
$\dfrac{a}{\left(\dfrac bc \right)} $

In the second question, I really can't tell.